# Is it possible distribute iOS application privately (to specific Apple IDs)

Tags: ios, app-store

The idea to distribute **release** version of iOS application to specified users only. This app shouldn't be available for any person except who was selected (using AppleID or something).

Is it possible to avoid using Enterprise Developer Program?

VPP as I understand will not work here, because app will be available to all business users.

Ad-Hoc distribution doesn't work for me: 6 months expiration, headache with udids, 100 device limitation.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to avoid Enterprise Developer Program (except the price :) )

Comment: This app will be for my client. Enterprise Developer Program required to support it time to time (1. application should be re-released in next 3 years due to certificate expiration, 2. required platform for distribution, App Store will not be available for distribution here)

Comment: I will use Enterprise Developer Program if will not find anything else.

Comment: B2B via the VPP is the only other option to Enterprise developer program, and sounds like the right solution here.  The VPP purchaser decides who they want to provide the app to; It is provided by MDM or Apple Configurator

Comment: I think Enterprise is the only way to go, else just make private login mechanism

Comment: @Paulw11, but VPP purchaser is anybody who was approved to be as VPP. So here to way to select concrete VPP purchaser.

Comment: What do you mean?  The VPP purchaser is the company you nominate. They then control which of their users they distribute the app to. Other VPP members (other companies) cannot access your app. See https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

Comment: @Paulw11 confirmed. Just tested. Works. Thanks!